# python json.loads string "0.0" is fine, but "0.0.0" throws exception

Tags: python, json

I expect input data as json, but I got "0.0" and my code crashed. So I added exception, but in example below it`s not working and **not throwing exception**:

```
import json
msg_payload="0.0"
try:
        a = json.loads(msg_payload)
except ValueError, e:
        print("JSON FAIL")
print a
```

and this code throw exception:

```
import json
msg_payload="0.0.0"
try:
        a = json.loads(msg_payload)
except ValueError, e:
        print("JSON FAIL")
print a
```

So why there no exception with **string** "0.0" and exception with **string** "0.0.0"

Comment: Because `0.0` is a valid float number.

Comment: If you want it to be parsed as a string, the string needs to contain literal quotes. `msg_payload='"0.0.0"'`

Answer (score 2):

The payload `0.0` is valid JSON code consisting of only a single floating point number. `0.0.0` is not since strings need to be encapsulated with quotation marks.

If you want `0.0` to produce an error, you should add your own restrictions on the *structure* of the JSON code.

Answer (score 0):

`'0.0.0'` is not a valid JSON format. It cannot be decoded like that. It's not a float and it's not a string either. To load it as a string you need to use double quotes `'"0.0.0"'`.